# SQL - Count amount of higher values starting with the lowest

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with two attributes car and ID. The query is already sorted with "order by ID asc"

How is it possible to list every car with the amount of higher IDs starting at the lowest?  How do I iterate through the values and count for each value the amount of higher values

for example:

```
blue car 1
red car 1
green car 2
yellow car 2
```

should be:

```
blue car 2
red car 2
green car 0 
yellow car 0
```

Comment: _The table is already sorted with "order by ID asc"_ NO, tables are not sorted, but a query can be sorted

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Comment: *should be* Why? unclear... explain in details.

Comment: I want to iterate through the IDs and count the amount of higher IDs. After that I want to change the current ID into that excact number of higher IDs. 
So that blue car with ID 1 has two cars with higher IDs. So it's ID turns into 2

Comment: Please edit you r question to incorporate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would just add another column to my query to get the count like:

```
select c.car, c.id, 
      (select count(id) from cars cc where cc.id > c.id) as higheridcount
from cars c
order by id asc
```